# Change Environment variables through sudo script

Tags: sudo, environment-variables, bashrc

I have a script *script_xy.sh*, which I have to execute via `sudo`.
In this script I modify environment variables and when I add the line `source ${BASHRC}` nothing happens, because it doesn't refer on the returning shell (however, a new shell with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> has the changes).

What I have tried. but didn't work since it also doesn't refer on the parent shell:

```
sudo -H -u $USER bash -c "source ${BASHRC}"
```

⟹ Is there a way to refresh the environment in the shell, where the sudo-script has been executed?

Comment: You can affect the environment of a parent shell from a child process. You can, of course, run `~/.bashrc` *after* the sudo command, separately.

Comment: @muru Yes of course I can affect the changes via sourcing bashrc after the script but inside the script it has no effect. And there are commands in the script which need the env variables and so don't work.

Comment: @muru: s/can/can't/

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson ah, dammit, typo